# Оцентровка контрола в панели

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется панель

```
this.LeftPage.AutoSize = true;
this.LeftPage.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(330, 500);
this.LeftPage.Name = "LeftPage";
this.LeftPage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(330, 0);
```

В неё подгружается контрол вот таким образом

```
public Main() {
    InitializeComponent();
    ToC toc = new ToC();
    LeftPage.Controls.Add(toc);
}
```

Размер контрола по ширине 230, размер панели, 330 (как видно из кода).
Как оцентровать контрол по горизонтали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойства [Control.Anchor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx) и/или [Control.Dock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx) позволяют привязывать контролы к границам контейнера. Размер/положение контрола будет меняться как только изменится размер Parent'а.

Например, есть панель с Width=100, Height=100.
На этой панели надо разместить кнопку с Left=10, Top=10.
Надо чтобы границы кнопки были привязаны к границам панели. Т.е. при смещении границ панели, смещались границы кнопки. В такой ситуации надо поменять свойства у кнопки.
Для привязки по горизонтали, примерно так:

```
toc.Dock = DockStyle.None;
toc.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
```

Если Width у панели и контрола не будут меняться, то при добавлении контрола в панель, надо указать Left для контрола

```
toc.Left = (panel.ClientSize.Width - toc.Width) / 2;
```

---

UPDATE:

Для размещение контролов в виде таблицы можно использовать [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: а -1 -- хотите сказать, что Anchor и/или Dock не работают?

Comment: Это не я минусовал. Я пока еще ничего не хочу сказать, сейчас проверять буду. Однако, не центрует.

Comment: Я могу, конечно, обернуть контрол в таблицу из 3 колонок и задать крайним 100%, а центральному автосайз, но это не очень правильный вариант, как мне кажется. Хотя 100% работающий при любых условиях.

Comment: таблица - не нужна. я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Наверное либо я не так написал, либо Вы меня не так поняли.
Попробую написать подбробнее какой результат я хочу получить.

Comment: Имеется панель с шириной 300 и динамической высотой. В эту панель могут встраиваться различного размера контролы, как по высоте, так и по ширине. Сама панель не меняет своей ширины. Необходимо, чтобы контрол, который встроился в панель был оцентрован в ней по горизонтали.

Т.е. имея панель 300 и контрол 200, у него должен быть отступ слева и справа по 50, а если контрол 100 - то по 100 отступы по краям.

Comment: если у панели не меняется ширина, и она вам известна, и ширина контрола - известна, то просто укажите Left у контрола. -- добавил в ответ.

Comment: Вручную писать каждому контролу отступы? Хм, решение с таблицей выглядит проще и при этом работает независимо от того, что именно я захочу подгрузить в панель, встроенную в центральную ячейку. Я так понимаю какого либо универсального "гибкого" решения нет для контрола "неизвестного размера"?

Comment: можно не вручную; определите массив параметров, читайте их в цикле и примените к контролам. да, в WinForms много нет из того, что добавили в WPF.

Comment: Хм. Спасибо за идею, надо попробовать на WPF реализовать, пока не сильно далеко продвинулся. На сим я так полагаю вопрос можно закрыть. Спасибо за участие.